# How to create a dotplot from a frequency table?

Tags: r

I am very new to R (and programming in general) and am experiencing a great deal of difficulty in creating a dot plot. I want to create a dot plot from data that I have stored in a data frame named "Table" that has two columns, "Results" and "Frequency." [Here is a screenshot of "Table."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJjpZ.png) And here is a representative dataset of "Table" in a plain text format which I generated via
`dput(Table)`:

```
structure(list(Results = c(-4.4, -4.2, -4, -3.8, -3.6, -3.4, 
-3.2, -3, -2.8, -2.6, -2.4, -2.2, -2, -1.8, -1.6, -1.4, -1.2, 
-1, -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.2, 1.4, 
1.6, 1.8, 2, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 2.8, 3, 3.2, 3.4, 3.6, 3.8, 4, 4.2, 
4.4), Frequency = c(2, 5, 14, 39, 80, 156, 280, 484, 770, 1178, 
1705, 2395, 3217, 4197, 5258, 6433, 7598, 8771, 9808, 10738, 
11405, 11856, 11978, 11856, 11405, 10738, 9808, 8771, 7598, 6433, 
5258, 4197, 3217, 2395, 1705, 1178, 770, 484, 280, 156, 80, 39, 
14, 5, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 45L), class = "data.frame")
```

I searched for everything I could think of relating to my problem, but I was unable to find anything that actually helped. Most of what I found seemed to assume that I was using a list or vector with the results written out n times, where n is the frequency of the results.
Here is an example of what I mean using the data from the first two rows of "Table":

```
Vector <- c(-4.4,-4.4,-4.2,-4.2,-4.2,-4.2,-4.2)
dotchart(Vector)
```

Hopefully this all makes sense!

Edit: User M.Viking supplied me with a solution for my problem!:

```
dotchart(df$Frequency, labels=df$Results)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(Table)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: Is this what you are after: `dotchart(df$Frequency, labels=df$Results)`

Comment: @M.Viking Yes! Thank you very much!